# How to ignore parsing errors in pandoc?

Tags: mediawiki, pandoc

I have a bulk of wikipedia articles. While parsing them with pandoc I encountered incorrect written tables in format:

```
{| class=wikitable style=text-align:center;font-size:90%
!width=100| <... more attrs>
```

As you see in attr `class=wikitable`, `wikitable` is not wrapped by `""`. And pandoc generates error for this

```
pandoc:
Error:
"source" (line 198, column 10):
unexpected "w"
expecting "\""
```

Is it possible to make pandoc to support this kind of tables or ignore parsing errors?

Comment: I think this is almost certainly a bug. It would be best to report it to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues)

Comment: I hate saying it... but perhaps you have to try another parser? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers The MediaWiki parser's approach is just "do the best you can and then run the output through Tidy!".